# Removing Text Shadow

Tags: text, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, shadow

I'm not sure if this is changeable, but I'm noticing a slight shadow on the title of my custom navigation controller.

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnMYS.jpg

It's making the text look blurry, which is kind of annoying.

This is the code I'm using: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255.0 green:54.0/255.0 blue:61.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue-Bold" size:0.0],UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]];`

Any idea how to remove the shadow on the title?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Place this in your AppDelegate

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: This only removes the shadow from beneath the UINavigationBar. 
Not within the title.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it transparent:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: 
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:52.0/255.0 green:54.0/255.0 blue:61.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue-Bold" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```